# Javascript regex to match fully qualified domain name, without protocol, optional subdomain

Tags: javascript, regex

I haven't been able to find this one and what I'm trying isn't quite working out for me.

I want to match only domains that:

- don't contain a protocol (http, https, ftp)
- optionally include a subdomain
- don't **start** with a hyphen but **can** contain a hyphen

Example domains that would match:

- domain.com
- example.domain.com
- example.domain-hyphen.com
- www.domain.com
- example.museum

Example domains that would **not** match:

- http://example.com
- subdomain.-example.com
- example.com/parameter
- example.com?anything
- www.subdomain.domain.com

What I've currently got:

```
/^(?!:\/\/)(^[a-zA-Z0-9])?.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}?$/i
```

It's not matching protocols, allowing hyphen inside the domain, not allowing trailing characters after the TLD, and is allowing a subdomain (but only 1 character).

I still need to allow subdomains of any length, not allow www.subdomain.domain.com and not allow a leading hyphen.

Comment: How do you define "domain" then? Every word with at least one dot in it?

Comment: Not sure I understand. `domain` precedes the TLD and can only contain letters, numbers and a hyphen.

Comment: Well, that was my (failed) attempt at allowing subdomains. Basically that's where I got stuck and the last thing I added to this regex.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
/^(?!:\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}?$/i
```

Comment: I know this is old, but it should be updated to allow domains such as .photography, which has more than 6 characters

Comment: @dda I see that you have deleted your TSE profile (I came to know after losing 310 points). Although I don't have any right to ask, I hope everything is well. That forum is boring without your edits.

Comment: @HankyPanky One of my answers was edited, against, my wish, and locked, to prevent to change it back. It was the last straw of a series of things that made me regret joining TSE in the first place. It became obvious my work wasn't appreciated by the moderators...

Comment: I can't say anything on behalf of the moderators then but I have always found your contribution valuable. I used to think you'd make a great moderator one day (I still think so). I'm disappointed to see you go and I hope you guys sort it out and be back.

Comment: @HankyPanky Also, right after I left, there was an attempt at downvoting me 27 times in a row on Expats (where I am no longer active either). This was quickly overturned, but it obviously was a TSE member who was unhappy with the points loss. I also on chat that the person who censored my answer was unhappy about my leaving. Should I thought about his actions first. But I also saw that not everybody was unhappy... So, farewell.

Comment: I don’t know why TSE has become like that lately but then it’s such a big crowd that I can’t ever speak for someone. I will definitely miss your contribution and I hope you do come back. A few people not doing the right thing don’t really represent the whole community.

Comment: doesn't work with new domains, even something as simple as inte.io failed

Answer (score 4):

Let's analyse your regex:

> ```
> ^(?!:\/\/)
> ```

This is pretty useless. While it indicates the intention of the regex, it's unnecessary since the following characters are not allowed to contain slashes anyway.

> ```
> (^[a-zA-Z0-9])?.
> ```

I think you wanted this to be `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)?`. Your dot is not escaped, and would be preceded by only one optional character at the string beginning.

> ```
> [a-zA-Z0-9-]+
> ```

If you want this not to begin with a hyphen, you either could use a negative lookahead or better just `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*`.

> ```
> \.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}?
> ```

Not sure what the question mark does here. There's no backtracking anyway?

> ```
> /i
> ```

This renders the explicit `[a-zA-Z]` useless, one would be enough. Or omit the `i` flag.

All these things together, we will end up with

```
/^([a-z0-9]+\.)?[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i
```

Comment: I know this is old, but it should be updated to allow domains such as .photography, which has more than 6 characters

Comment: Sure, however I've only analyzed the regex that was presented in the question and got it working (without commenting on the meaning)

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry... But when I saw it I thought if people hunt for the answer they might copy this one without even considering its limitations... So leave it as is

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/KByADagF3Z)

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The RegEx I came up with while doing the Hostname/FQDN validation in Javascript:

**FQDN:**

`^(?!:\/\/)(?!.{256,})(([a-z0-9][a-z0-9_-]*?\.)+?[a-z]{2,6}?)$/i`

**Hostname or FQDN**

`^(?!:\/\/)(?!.{256,})(([a-z0-9][a-z0-9_-]*?)|([a-z0-9][a-z0-9_-]*?\.)+?[a-z]{2,6}?)$/i`

Both expressions use lookahead to check the total string length, which can be up to 255 characters. They also do a lazy check `.{x,y}?`.

Note that it is using case insensitive match `/i`.